# Where does MySQL store files when it's "copying to tmp table"

Tags: mysql

I've got a query that's stalling, and I have no idea why. It looks sensible, but it runs "forever" (I went and had my lunch and left it running, hadn't finished 20 mins later).

Looking at "SHOW PROCESSLIST", I see my connection has the status "Copying to tmp table".

I looked in my my.cnf, and it looks like temp files should be in /tmp, but there's nothing relating to MySQL in there (there's only 2 directories, both empty).

To help me diagnose what was wrong, I thought I'd have a look at the temporary file it was supposedly copying to. If it was huge, I must have messed up a query. If not, perhaps it's a bug.

But I can't figure out where it's storing them. Is it an in-memory "file"?

I'm running MySQL 5.1.31 on a Ubuntu 9.04 JeOS install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many temporary tables can and will be created in-memory. Whether a table will be created in-memory or on-disk is determined by a few factors like size of the table, structure (Does it have BLOBs) and a few more.

I suggest you read up on [TMP_TABLE_SIZE and MAX_HEAP_TABL\E_SIZE](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/19/tmp_table_size-and-max_heap_table_size/) to gain insight on how temporary tables work.

You can check the output of

```
mysql> show status like '%tmp%';
```

if you are actually creating on-disk tables. Note, however, that the actual temporary table file will be of little to no help in determining if there is a problem.

You could also try to [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) your query and see how well it should perform.

Comment: Of course, my didn't I think of EXPLAIN?!

Many thanks for the informative links, too.

Answer (score 4):

in debian - by default in /tmp [ afair ]

whenever in doubt just run

```
lsof|grep -i mysqld
```

mysql's temporary files are deleted just after creation - they show up on lsof, but not in ls ; they do take disk space until file handles are closed.

Comment: Wasn't me, I found this useful, edited it slightly as it was returning PHP's mysql libs too (box is a webserver also).
I used:
    lsof | grep -iE "^mysqld.*?/tmp"

Comment: Nice, thanks.  I wonder why my mysql isn't following it's tmpfile settings, odd...

Answer (score 3):

It depends what kind of temporary table. If it says "Copy to temporary table" then it is an in-memory copy. If it says "Copy to temporary table on disk" then it has exceeded the size for in-memory temp tables and is dumping to disk.

In the event of the latter than it will be stored in the location defined by the `tmpdir` variable. You can find out what that is set to by:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mysql variable that indicates where the files will be stored:

`mysql> show variables like '%tmp%';`

Look for the tmpdir variable.  That will tell you where the tmp files are being stored.  If a temporary table is less than 'tmp_table_size' it will be memory based rather than disk based.